# Alternative to setClip()

Tags: java, awt

I've been trying to make a component draw outside its own bounds using SetClip(), but it turns out that this is immensely buggy and most of the internet seems to agree that it's not worth doing.

So, I am turning to you lovely people for help. Is there a way to draw outside a component's bounds? I need the bounds to stay where they are because they're registering mouseEntered and mouseExited events as well.

Comment: Are you targeting AWT or Swing?

Comment: @trashgod: Erm... I think I'm using a kind of mixture...? That doesn't really seem like a good idea now that I think about it...

Comment: There are some guidelines in [Mixing heavy and light components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For safety and security, [`setClip()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) "sets the user clip, which is independent of the clipping associated with device bounds and window visibility." If your components are in a visible `Container`, you can draw around them by overriding the container's `paint()` (or `paintComponent()` in Swing). The `getComponents()` method will give you an array of contained components from which you can get the locations in container coordinates.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. It would be nice to be able to just place the components in the container and not worry about painting each one manually. Well, if it's the only way, I might as well.

Comment: Oh, wait... I just understood what 'independent of the clipping associated with device bounds and window visibility' means. Thanks.